# How pass text in table as argument for .ajax function

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a table of data that is presented like so:

```
<table>
<tr><td>Value 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Value 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Value 3</td></tr>
</table>
```

I'd like to pass the text between the two "td" tags into an Ajax function; ideally you click on the table entry and the table entry's value will be used to form a SQL query via Ajax. I however do not know how to pass each unique table entry into the Ajax function; I can't provide different ids for each table entry because the table is generated dynamically from another SQL query, nor do I know how to set up an ajax function to recognize dynamically generated ids. What's the best way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a click event listener to the table td elements and pass the html content of the clicked element to your ajax function.

```
$("table td").click(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'path_to_file',
        data: { 
            'table_value' : $(this).html() 
        }
    });
});
```